# Mikrotik маршрутизация на входящие подключения

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, mikrotik

Есть сеть с интернетом `192.168.1.x/24` на TPLink и внутренняя сеть на роутере Mikrotik с адресами `192.168.0.x/24`. Mikrotik весь инет берёт из VPN с выделенным IP. Не может сервер принять HTML запросы из интернета по выделенному IP. Помогите с маршрутизацией.

```
роутер TPLink
192.168.1.50 -> 192.168.1.x/24
v
192.168.1.75
роутер Mikrotik
192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.x/24



/ip firewall>> export  
# dec/19/2018 07:58:11 by RouterOS 6.43
# software id = K4C1-ZJXH
#
# model = 951G-2HnD
# serial number = 642E06DFCExx

/ip firewall filter
add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=52.0.0.0/8 log=yes src-mac-address=00:00:1B:09:60:xx
add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=52.0.0.0/8 src-mac-address=00:00:1B:09:61:xx
add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=54.194.92.52 src-mac-address=E0:61:B2:32:BC:xx
add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=54.194.92.52 src-mac-address=E0:61:B2:32:BF:xx
add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=54.194.92.52 src-mac-address=E0:61:B2:32:BC:xx
add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=54.194.92.52 src-mac-address=E0:61:B2:32:BA:xx
add action=drop chain=input disabled=yes in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp src-port=53
add action=drop chain=input in-interface=pptp-out1 log=yes protocol=udp src-port=53
add action=accept chain=input protocol=icmp
add action=accept chain=input connection-state=established,related
add action=drop chain=input disabled=yes in-interface=bridge1WAN log=yes protocol=udp src-port=53
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward connection-state=established,related
add action=accept chain=forward connection-state=established,related
add action=drop chain=forward connection-state=invalid
add action=drop chain=forward connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new in-interface=bridge1WAN

/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 new-routing-mark=lan1 passthrough=no
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting new-routing-mark=pptp_rm passthrough=no src-address=192.168.0.2-192.168.0.254
add action=mark-connection chain=input dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 in-interface=bridge1WAN new-connection-mark=UpNetInput passthrough=no
add action=mark-routing chain=output connection-mark=UpNetInput new-routing-mark=UpNet passthrough=no

/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 out-interface=bridge1WAN out-interface-list=all routing-mark=lan1 src-address=192.168.0.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=!192.168.1.0/24 out-interface=pptp-out1
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=bridge1WAN time=6h-18h,sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="MySql server" dst-port=3306 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.72 to-ports=3306
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Alex SSH" dst-port=22 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.105 to-ports=22
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=Office dst-port=2013 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.113 to-ports=554
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Konez sklada" dst-port=2011 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.116 to-ports=554
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=Doroga dst-port=2014 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.114 to-ports=554
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="vid na sklad" dst-port=2009 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.109 to-ports=554
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="prihozka smotrja nad offisom" dst-port=2015 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.115 to-ports=554
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Vitrina smotrja nad dverju" dst-port=2010 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.110 to-ports=554
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="HTMLS Server Bit Himia" dst-port=443 in-interface=pptp-out1 log=yes protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.72 to-ports=443
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="HTML(80) Server Bit Himia" dst-port=80 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.72 to-ports=80
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Server Ubuntu SSH" dst-port=23 in-interface=pptp-out1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.72 to-ports=22
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat disabled=yes dst-port=1080 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.105 to-ports=80
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat disabled=yes dst-address=81.162.69.xx dst-port=2016 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.113 to-ports=80
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat disabled=yes out-interface=pppoe-out1
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat disabled=yes dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.66
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat disabled=yes src-address=192.168.1.0/24
add action=accept chain=srcnat connection-type=pptp disabled=yes out-interface=*A protocol=tcp

/ip route
add distance=10 gateway=pptp-out1 routing-mark=pptp_rm
add disabled=yes distance=1 gateway=bridge1WAN
add check-gateway=ping disabled=yes distance=1 gateway=172.16.xx.1
add distance=5 dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 gateway=pptp-out1
add distance=5 dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 gateway=bridge1WAN pref-src=192.168.1.75
add disabled=yes distance=1 dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 gateway=192.168.0.66
```

Что-то нужно чудить с mangle - я не понимаю как.

Comment: не видно что микротик "весь инет кидает на VPN" - видно что весь трафик помечается и видать потом идет в какой-то "VPN". Почему просто не использовать шлюз по умолчанию для pptp?

Comment: @dash1121 Я научным методом тыка нашёл способ: добавил сверху mangle. Но не могу понять почему в таблице NAT это не работает. `/ip firewall mangle ;
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 \
    new-routing-mark=lan1 passthrough=no ; /ip firewall nat ;
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 log=yes \
    out-interface=bridge1WAN out-interface-list=all routing-mark=lan1 \
    src-address=192.168.0.0/24`

Comment: nat всего лишь должен сработать, если ему что-то перепадет. посмотри работает ли это правило вообще - /ip firewall nat print stats Покажи маршруты и все правила /ip firewall export и /ip route export По тому что есть в вопросе видно что все пакеты от внутренней сети должны пойти в vpn, и не не будут попадать в nat на wan интерфейсе. А вот пинг с микротика до тплинка должен долетать, хотя может резаться каким-то еще правилом в файерволе.

Comment: @dash1121 Вопрос полностью изменил, выложил все настройки. Но с mangle никак не врубаюсь.

Comment: В routes: 1) точно сеть 192.168.0.0/24 лежит за pptp-out1 а не каким-то lan? 2)удалите routing-mark у маршрута по умолчанию - все данные будут туда сыпаться. В mangle: вообще все удалите оттуда - шлюз по умолчанию будет без метки, в сеть 192.168.1.0 попадет потому что есть прямой маршрут. В nat: 1) с masquerade оставь всего 2 правилла - add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=XXXX  Ну и вообще, сначала сделай минимальный рабочий конфиг, а потом вводи ограничения - рубануть пересылку от 192.168.1.0 в интернет всегда успеешь :)

Comment: @dash1121 Если я в NAT удаляю проверку маркировки, инет весь стразу утекает в открытую и сайт не подаёт сигнала. Пока-что еле пашут такие танцы.